# Move model in OpenGL by translate matrix instead of glTranslate()

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

My goal is moving object by arrow keys pressing. For this purpose in callback I create translate matrix from some offset and multiply it to world matrix. However it doesn't work - cube doesn't move by pressing keys. I also noticed using glTranslate() directly with setted offset works good but looks like crutch. I mean, I should use only translation matrices for any transformation of model.
Where is the problem in my code? How to fix it? Why glTranslate() works good? 
Minimal code example:

```
glm::mat4 mWorldMatrix;
glm::mat4 mViewMatrix;
glm::mat4 mProjMatrix;

void onKeyCallback(GLFWwindow*, int key, int scan, int action, int mods)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case GLFW_KEY_UP:
        {
            auto translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4{}, glm::vec3{ 0, 1, 0 });
            mWorldMatrix = mWorldMatrix * translationMatrix;
            break;
        }
        case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
        {
            auto translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4{}, glm::vec3{ 0, -1, 0 });
            mWorldMatrix = mWorldMatrix * translationMatrix;
            break;
        }
        case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
        {
            auto translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4{}, glm::vec3{ -1, 0, 0 });
            mWorldMatrix = mWorldMatrix * translationMatrix;
            break;
        }
        case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
        {
            auto translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4{}, glm::vec3{ 1, 0, 0 });
            mWorldMatrix = mWorldMatrix * translationMatrix;
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    const int weight = 640;
    const int height = 480;
    auto mWindow = glfwCreateWindow(weight, height, "TesT", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mWindow);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    mWorldMatrix = glm::mat4{ 1.0f };
    mViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3{ 0, 0, -1 },
                              glm::vec3{ 0, 0, 0 },
                              glm::vec3{ 0, 1, 0 });
    mProjMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f),
                                   static_cast<float>(weight) / height, 
                                   0.1f, 
                                   100.0f);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(mWindow, onKeyCallback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mWindow)) {
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glViewport(0,0, weight, height);

        auto modelViewMatrix = mViewMatrix * mWorldMatrix;
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadMatrixf(static_cast<const float*>(glm::value_ptr(modelViewMatrix)));

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
        glLoadMatrixf(static_cast<const float*>(glm::value_ptr(mProjMatrix)));

        Cube cube{ glm::vec3{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 1 }; //cube with center in {0.5} and side length 1
        auto vertices = cube.soup(); //vector of vertex

        glTranslatef(0 /* + offset.x*/, 0/* + offset.y*/, -5); //Setting offset here is work good
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (const auto& vertex : vertices)
        {
            glColor3f(vertex.position.x, vertex.position.y, vertex.position.z);
            glVertex3f(vertex.position.x, vertex.position.y, vertex.position.z);
        }
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(mWindow);
        glfwWaitEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a step where you apply the matrix to the vertex locations?  You init the verts fresh every time, but don't apply your varying matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack and fixed function. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).
Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

The projection matrix should be applied to the projection matrix stack and the model view matrix to the model view matrix stack.

There are 2 issues.

1. `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` is not a valid enum constant for [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) and will cause a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. The valid enum constant for the projection matrix mode is `GL_PROJECTION`. `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` would be used for reading the current projection matrix by [`glGetFloatv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml).
2. If you want to apply additional transformation to the model, then you have to choose the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix before. If the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix is "selected", this state is kept until it is changed again explicitly.

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(static_cast<const float*>(glm::value_ptr(modelViewMatrix)));

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // <----- `GL_PROJECTION` instead of `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`
glLoadMatrixf(static_cast<const float*>(glm::value_ptr(mProjMatrix)));

// [...]

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // <-------- specify `GL_MODELVIEW`
glTranslatef(0 /* + offset.x*/, 0/* + offset.y*/, -5); //Setting offset here is work good
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in every loop you set the cube to the original position. You should define these objects outside the loop. Then you can mutate them in the while loop.

In openGL lessons at the university I had very much use of a youtube series from "The Cherno". He made [openGL course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3gAzLwfIP0&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2).